# To be a reference in a skill/topic

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am struggling on how to say when someone is an expert on a certain topic or skill. Because it is not exactly the meaning I intend to give.

What I really want to say is like:
*"When you want to know about IT, ask John. He is the __________ in this topic within our group".*

Can I use the word "reference" to fill in the blank? is that usual?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ***...authority***?

Comment: or informally, *the go-to person*

Comment: No, "reference" is not appropriate in that context.

Comment: I agree, *reference* would sound odd. In a workplace setting, I sometimes refer to experts as an *expert*, or *lead*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "[reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference)" to fill in the blank here.

> "When you want to know about IT, ask John. He is the ___ in this topic within our group".

But you can "refer" to this person, who is an ___ in this topic.

A formal and most commonly used word would be:

**Expert** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expert)

> A person who is very knowledgeable about or skilful in a particular area
>
> *"an expert in health care"*

*synonyms:* specialist, authority, pundit, guru, oracle; adept, maestro, virtuoso, master, past master, professional, genius, wizard; connoisseur, aficionado, one of the cognoscenti, cognoscente, doyen, savant

If you want something less formal:

**Go-to** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-to)

> always helpful : producing desired results or information when needed
>
> relied on for expert knowledge or skill
>
> *"the company's go-to guy"*
> *"He's the go-to guy in the office for tax information"*

Even more informal, especially if it's the IT field:

**Ninja** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ninja)

> 1.1 <sub><sup>[OFTEN WITH MODIFIER]</sup></sub> *informal* A person who excels in a particular skill or activity:
>
> *"My goal as marketing ninja is to get Thomas to spend less time in London, and more time on a plane, visiting his other ports of call."*
> *"the courses vary—you don’t have to be a computer ninja to apply"*

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [panjandrum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/panjandrum)